# Mobile legends not compatible after unity fix

Tags: android-x86

I want to play mlbb on pc, but it gets black after logo phase. Because its unity game I patched unity fix. Others game like granny now works but mlbb vanishes if installed. Its in data/app. If I uninstall with pm and install, it says not  compatible.

Pm install says :
cant find matching adis,could not extract native resources.

I managed to get it run on primeos somehow. But can't do it anymore.

Comment: May be you are trying to install an ARMv7/v8a only app on an x86 emulator?

Comment: I also tried armv8 version of soulknight. It works. Also previous version of mlbb worked only in phoenix os. And some how I managed to run new one in prime os , don't know how. But I used unity fix than and it didn't show compatibility issue. Now when I switched to DM I can't work it anymore even on primeos

Comment: Why would it be not compatible when I have arm layer for arm games

Comment: Do u know how unity fix works